# Regex to extract expressions from input string

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to use a regular expression to extract expressions in the format of "operand operator operand" from a input string. The operands may be any single words or quoted phrases and the operator between operands will be the tilde sign followed by a numeral. The expression might occur n number of times within the input string. What's wrong in my regex?

```
package test;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ExpressionExtractor {

    private static final String operator = "\\s+\\~{1}\\d+\\s+";
    private static final String quotedWords = "[\"|'|“][A-Za-zÀ-ü0-9\\\\.\\/\\-,\\*\\s]+[\"|'|“]";
    private static final String singleWords = "[A-Za-zÀ-ü0-9\\\\.\\/\\-,\\*]+";
    private static final String operand = quotedWords+"|"+singleWords;
    private static final Pattern expressionPattern = Pattern.compile("("+operand + operator +operand+")");
    private static final Pattern operatorPattern = Pattern.compile(operator);

    public static Matcher evaluateExpression(String input) {
        return expressionPattern.matcher(input);
    }
}
```

A test case with the expected results:

```
package test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ExpressionExtractorUnitTest {

    @Test
    public void testExpressionExtractor() {
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList("firstWord ~20 secondWord"), find("any word firstWord ~20 secondWord one more word"));
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList("mother-in-law ~8 long-Word"), find("start of sentence mother-in-law ~8 long-Word one sentence"));
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList("firstWord ~7 secondWord", "word ~8 \"complex expression\""), 
                find("more complex expression firstWord ~7 secondWord with another word ~8 \"complex expression\" continued"));
    }

    private List<String> find(String expression) {
        Matcher matcher = ExpressionExtractor.evaluateExpression(expression);
        List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
        while (matcher.find()) {
            tokens.add(matcher.group());
        }
        return tokens;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may test your regular expressions on https://regex101.com/ , this website explains the parts of your expression. I think you have too many backslashes in ```\\\\.``` and the pipes in ```[\"|'|“]``` should be removed

Comment: the moment you start talking about operators you are moving into the realm of grammars. Some expressions cannot be parsed by regex, and it would be wrong to do it even if you can. In fact by using separate variables for your regex you already simulate a grammar.

Comment: your specific problem here is that you have multiple pipes in the same match group , so effectively you are matching against **singleWords** pattern like this: "(sometihng|something|singleWord)

Comment: Got rid of the pipes. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your code includes a nice unit test, here are suggested fixes/changes:

- You don't need to specify character number if it is 1 so "~{1}" can become "~". You don't need to escape the tilde character, so "\s+\~{1}\d+\s+" can become "\s+~\d+\s+". There if you don't like the "picket fence" you can use another character, for example like this

> ```
> String operator = "!s+~!d+!s+".replace('!','\\').
> ```

- I find the expression fro quoted words too complicated to follow. You can try a a group starting with quote character, followed by 0 or more non-quote characters and then followed by a quote. Also, you don't need pipe within square brackets

> ```
> String quotedWords = "[\"|'|“][^\"|'|“]*[\"|'|“]";
> ```

- In order to match many alternative patterns you have to add extra parenthesis for each group

> ```
> expressionPattern = Pattern.compile("(" + operand + ")(" +operator + ")(" +operand + ")");
> ```

This will make the tests pass. However, you might consider using a grammar parser library like ANTLR. There you could easily go to nested expressions and get the abstract syntax tree (AST)